# Commutator of two Lorentz charges/angular momenta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, string-theory, commutator

In Barton Zwieback's book "A first course in string theory" page 261, we calculated a Lorentz charge/angular momentum $M^{-I}$ of the open bosonic string in the light-cone formulation to be;
$$
M^{-I} = x_{0}^{-}p^{I} - \frac{1}{4\alpha^{'}p^+}\left(x_{0}^I\left(L_{0}^\perp + a\right) + \left(L_{0}^\perp + a\right) x_{0}^I\right)\\
 - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2\alpha^{'}}p^+}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n}\left(L_{-n}^{\perp}\alpha_{n}^I - \alpha_{-n}^IL_{n}^{\perp}\right).\tag{12.151}$$
Then, he said that that calculating the commutator $[M^{-I}, M^{-J}]$ is very long and not easy. he writes then;
$$
[M^{-I}, M^{-J}] = - \frac{1}{\alpha^{'}p^{+2}}\sum_{m\ge1} \left(\alpha_{-m}^{I}\alpha_{m}^{I} - \alpha_{-m}^{J}\alpha_{-m}^{J}\right)\\ \times \left\{m \left[1 -\frac{1}{24} (D-2)\right] + \frac{1}{m}\left[\frac{1}{24} (D-2) + a\right]\right\}.\tag{12.152}
$$
My question is, how can someone prove such result? I tried to find a paper or something on internet, but no progress till now.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly speaking Ref. 2 argues on general grounds an ansatz (2.3.24) for the angular momentum commutator, and then sandwiches$^1$ the commutator between a bra and ket vacuum state to simplify the calculation of the coefficients (2.3.35) in the ansatz.

References:

1. B. Zwiebach, *A first course in String Theory,* 2nd edition, 2009; section 12.5, eq. (12.152).
2. M.B. Green, J.H. Schwarz and E. Witten, *Superstring theory,* Vol. 1, 1986; section 2.3, eqs. (2.3.24+35).

--

$^1$ A similar sandwich trick is often applied to simplify the calculation of the central charge in the [Virasoro algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra), cf. e.g. eq. (2.2.31) in Ref. 2.